# Convert object column to datetime column in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a weird format in my `object`column in python:

```
 2020-08-13-09.41.16.474284
```

How can i convert that column to datetime? I tried:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col', format='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.%f')
```

but that leads to an error:  `ValueError: time data '2020-08-13-10.59.43.324747' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.%f' (match)`

Comment: There is typo `M` - `pd.to_datetime(df['col', format='%Y-%m-%D.%H.%M.%f')`

Comment: see my edit, the `%f`format is not correct how can i fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You need `.` for match format:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.%f')
```

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you.